# SQL Combine Sum with Rounding decimal SQL2008

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table which contains hours and minutes for staff from a custom time sheet app we've developed in house. I am able to get the sum of hours and I am also able to round and divide the minutes but I can only do this separately. I need to be able to combine this. In my 2 Statements below, I am looking for specific parameters based on date and when a user clocks in. My results are two separate answers 1.070000 and 8.0000. This result should be 9.07. I know I am missing a lot but need some help with combining these results into one. How do i perform this?

Example:

```
select (SUM(hrs)) as Total_Hrs 
from dbo.TLA_Totals 
WHERE event_name like '%Clock%' AND dte_dd = 01 and dte_ddd = 'Sun' 
and dte_mm = 01 and dte_yyyy = 2017

select ROUND(SUM(mins) / 60.0, 2) as Total_Minutes 
from TLA_Totals 
where dte_dd = 01 and dte_mm = 01
```

Comment: So are you getting `8.0000` for the first `Select` and `1.070000` for the second `Select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
select TotalTime = sum(Total_Hrs)
from
(
    select (SUM(hrs)) as Total_Hrs 
    from dbo.TLA_Totals 
    WHERE event_name like '%Clock%' AND dte_dd = 01 and dte_ddd = 'Sun' 
    and dte_mm = 01 and dte_yyyy = 2017

    UNION ALL

    select ROUND(SUM(mins) / 60.0, 2) as Total_Minutes 
    from TLA_Totals 
    where dte_dd = 01 and dte_mm = 01
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit puzzled, but you could try to join the two queries by performing them separateley, then adding the two values together - A WITH statment might also be used

```
    SELECT Q1.Total_Hrs  + CA.Total_Minutes AS Grand_Total FROM  (select (SUM(hrs)) as Total_Hrs 
from dbo.TLA_Totals 
WHERE event_name like '%Clock%' AND dte_dd = 01 and dte_ddd = 'Sun' 
and dte_mm = 01 and dte_yyyy = 2017) Q1
CROSS APPLY (
select ROUND(SUM(mins) / 60.0, 2) as Total_Minutes 
from TLA_Totals 
where dte_dd = 01 and dte_mm = 01) CA
```